# Isolating the value of an array variable in a string

Tags: php, regex

Let's say I have a line in a php file:

```
$config['fw_ls'] = 'some value';
```

I want to get the values between the quotes. What I tried are combinations like:

```
preg_match('/\$config\[\'fw_ls\'\] = \'([^\'])*\';/',$sData,$aK);
var_dump($aK);
```

Sadly I can't seem to get the value between the quotes, in above example it returns the character 't'. I really don't understand what I'm doing wrong. I'd expect the regex would search starting from the quote and get everything until it finds another quote. But that doesn't seem to be quite right.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Which output is it you want?

Comment: This seems a bad way of attacking the real problem. Please tell us more about that instead of focusing on one particular attempt to solve it.

Comment: I think you're missing something in your explanation, because the value between the quotes is the whole value.

Comment: here is what you need : preg_match('/=\s+\'(.*)?\'/',$sData,$aK); I am not posting this as an answer because there is a high probably that your approach is wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
$text = "\$config['fw_ls'] = 'some value';";
preg_match("#\\\$config\['fw_ls'\]\s*=\s*'([^']+)';#", $text, $match);
print_r($match);

Array
(
    [0] => $config['fw_ls'] = 'some value';
    [1] => some value
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use a parser, then get things like array index values. Here is an example of an open source php parser (in PHP):

https://github.com/nikic/PHP-Parser

regexes are not parsers, so it's hard to tell based on your question if you are trying to parse arbitray php lines, or if this is a special case where regexes could be your friend.